# Multiple background color overlapping each other

Tags: html, css, angular

[image]

Can anyone please explain to me what is going on over here, I am trying to override the background color to dodgerblue but for some reason the white background color is also being rendered underneath it.

I have the following snippet inside my css file.

```
.modal-content {
  color: $dropdown-text;
  background-color: dodgerblue ;
  opacity: 0.9;
 }
```

I have an angular 2 project and for some reason I cannot override the background color.

Here are the outputs with and without the white background color.[image: Without white background]

Here is the other one.
[image: With the white background]

Any help with is will be much appreciated.

Comment: Its a single pop up, why do you think I am using multiple pop up? Not really a frontend guy over here.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You use opacity. Set opacity: 1 to modal-content

Comment: I have updated the snapshot to better reflect the issue I am facing, Its not down to opacity.

Comment: as you can see the previous background-color style is strikethrough. It means, it doesn't can affect to your element.
What effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: Exactly, that strike through part shouldn't have any effect but for some crazy reason it is still being applied, as you can see, when I uncheck it I get the proper color or the color I want with the opacity but by default it is not like that, As default it is overlapping the blue color over the white color for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your opacity needs to be set to 1 not 0.9.

Also check that your css rule is the last one to be run by the browser. If you're trying to overwrite a rule, you need to load your libraries' css files in the header first, then your style.css last so you're changes overwrite the base library styles.

Comment: I have updated the snapshot to better reflect the issue I am facing, Its not down to opacity. The problem is that 2 background colors are being populated one over the other for the same class model-content.

Answer (score 0):

Why second time opacity show 0.5 it should be as in first 0.9. and also modal content should not be with opacity, it should be hard without opacity.

Set below property to modal instead of modalContent.

Also try with important property for back-color;

```
.modal, modal {
   color: #7d7d7d;
   background-color: dodgerblue !important ;
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

Comment: It doesn't help, all I am getting is a white background then.

Comment: can you please post as plunkar

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that will be possible.